# Heroku architecture for running different applications but on the same domain

Tags: heroku

I have a unique set-up I am trying to determine if Heroku can accommodate.  There is so much marketing around polygot applications, but only one example I can actually find!

My application consists of:

1. A website written in **Django**
2. A separate **Java** application, which takes files uploaded by users, parses them, and stores the data in a database
3. A shared database accessible by both applications

Because these user-uploaded files can be enormous, I want the uploaded file to go directly to the Java application.  My preferred architecture is:

1. The Django-generated webpage displays the upload form.
2. The form does an AJAX submit to the Java application
3. The browser starts polling the database to see if the Java application has inserted the data
4. Meanwhile the Java application does its thing w/ the user-uploaded file and updates the database when it's done
5. The Django webpage AJAX-refreshes a div with the results of the user upload once the polling mechanism sees that the upload is complete

The big issue I can't figure out here is if I can get both the Django the Java apps either running on the same set of dynos or on different dynos but under the **same domain** to avoid AJAX cross-domain issues.  Does Heroku support URL-level routing?  For ex:

1. Django application available at http://www.myawesomewebsite.com
2. Java application available at http://www.myawesomewebsite.com/javaurl/

If this is not possible, does anyone have any ideas for work-arounds?  I know I could have the user upload the file to Django and have Django send the request to Java from the server-side instead of the client side, but that's an awful lot of passing around of enormous files.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not support the ability to route via the URL. Polyglot components should exist as their own subdomains and operate in a cross-domain fashion.

As a side-note: Have you considered directly uploading to S3 instead of uploading to your app on Heroku which will then (presumably) upload to S3. If you're dealing with cross-domain file uploads this is worth considering for its high level of scalability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about the routing!  Good to know for sure!  Regarding your S3 suggestion, that actually is where I'm ultimately storing the file, but I'd still need the Java web server to send back to the browser some kind of response acknowledging receipt of the parsing request, and if the Java app is on a subdomain, I can't get at that response b/c of the crossdomain issues.  Is there just no way to make this all work on the client-side on Heroku?  If I do it on the server side, then the large file is passed around 2 or 3x between S3 and the two apps...  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: When you say "acknowledging the receipt of the parsing request" do you mean of the upload to S3 or is there some additional parsing of the file that occurs? Either way, the java app can do whatever post-processing of the file that's required and save it's progress to a shared resource like the db or memcached that the Python app can query and return back to the browser. So the only app doing any communication with the browser is the Python one and all communication between the two apps is done on the backend. Not sure if that clarifies anything.

Comment: Well, that is what I mentioned in the last paragraph of my question as my Plan B.  I was just hoping it could all be done on the front-end for performance reasons.  Oh well.  Thanks for taking time time to help!